# Value gets overwritten in Runnable class - Java

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I am facing a problem with a Runnable class. The value that is passed to the runnable class is overwritten by the last value it received when the same value is passed to another class. 
The function of the runnable class is to pass the values to another function in another class to print them. But only the last value received by the Runnable class is printed.

Here is my code,
This is the main class from where the values are passed.

```
public class MainClass {
    private int intVal = -1;
    public void MainMethod() {
        ExecutorUtil theExecutor = ExecutorUtil.GetInstance();
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            intVal = i;
            synchronized (this) {
                theExecutor.SubmitTask(new ActionExecutor(intVal));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the executorUtil that I use to call the thread.

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;

public class ExecutorUtil {
    private static ExecutorUtil theInstance;
    private ExecutorService theExecutor;
    private BlockingQueue<Runnable> theQueue;



    protected ExecutorUtil() {
        theExecutor = CreateThreadPoolExecutor();
    }

    private ExecutorService CreateThreadPoolExecutor() {
        theQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>();
        ThreadPoolExecutor threadPoolExecutor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(10, 10, 900, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.SECONDS, theQueue);
        threadPoolExecutor.allowCoreThreadTimeOut(true);
        return threadPoolExecutor;
    }

    public static ExecutorUtil GetInstance() {
        if (theInstance == null) {
            synchronized(ExecutorUtil.class) {
                if (theInstance == null) {
                    theInstance = new ExecutorUtil();
                }
            }
        }
        return theInstance;
    }

    public void SubmitTask(Runnable runnable) {
        theExecutor.submit(runnable);
    }
}
```

This is the thread that passes the received value to the function that prints these values.

```
public class ActionExecutor implements Runnable {
    int iVal = -1;
    public ActionExecutor(int iVal) {
        this.iVal = iVal;
    }
    public void run() {
        SecondClass sc = new SecondClass();
        sc.printIntVal(iVal);
    }
}
```

And this is the class that prints the values.

```
public class SecondClass {
    public void printIntVal(int i) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Expected Output:

```
0
1
2
```

Obtained Output:

```
2
2
2
```

No idea why this is behaving in this way!

**UPDATE:**

The issue occurs only when a non-primitive data type is used. In my example here, I've used an integer value (intVal). Since java passes the value for primitive data types, the output was obtained as expected. But in my original code, I've used a JSONObject. And since java passes the reference of the object for non-primitive data types, the value was over-written.

I have solved this by creating new JSONObject for each iteration.

Comment: In general, your code contains a lot of incorrect multi-threading solutions that will lead to all kind of subtle hard to solve conditions. Apart from that the code conventions you are using are far off from what is standard in Java development, making the code hard to read.

Comment: Actually , this is not the original code. I have simplified the original code, so that it is easy for other SO users to understand my problem!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that somewhere you have **static** field, which store your number.
So, I suppose, that you have 3 instances of ActionExecutor, but it looks like field has static modifier, so each of this instance will have latest value.

Check this case...

Comment: No, I dont have any static fields.

Comment: The values that are printed in ActionExecutor before calling sc.printIntVal() are 0, 1 and 2. But inside SecondClass they are printed as 2, 2 and 2

Answer (score 0):

So after I read your question and studied your code I might as well try it out. And lo and behold it's working as expected. The only difference here is that there is a race condition so the output my vary in order, but it will not print the same numbers. 
Output might

- 1st: `0 1 2`
- 2nd: `0 1 2`
- 3rd: `2 1 0`

Here is the full code to try it out:

```
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;

public class MainClass {

     private int intVal = -1;
        public void MainMethod() {
            ExecutorUtil theExecutor = ExecutorUtil.GetInstance();
            for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                intVal = i;
                synchronized (this) {
                    theExecutor.SubmitTask(new ActionExecutor(intVal));
                }
            }
        }

        public class ActionExecutor implements Runnable {
            int iVal = -1;
            public ActionExecutor(int iVal) {
                this.iVal = iVal;
            }
            public void run() {
                SecondClass sc = new SecondClass();
                sc.printIntVal(iVal);
            }
        }
        public class SecondClass {
            public void printIntVal(int i) {
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        }

        public static class ExecutorUtil {
          private static ExecutorUtil theInstance;
            private ExecutorService theExecutor;
            private BlockingQueue<Runnable> theQueue;



            protected ExecutorUtil() {
                theExecutor = CreateThreadPoolExecutor();
            }

            private ExecutorService CreateThreadPoolExecutor() {
                theQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>();
                ThreadPoolExecutor threadPoolExecutor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(10, 10, 900, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.SECONDS, theQueue);
                threadPoolExecutor.allowCoreThreadTimeOut(true);
                return threadPoolExecutor;
            }

            public static ExecutorUtil GetInstance() {
                if (theInstance == null) {
                    synchronized(ExecutorUtil.class) {
                        if (theInstance == null) {
                            theInstance = new ExecutorUtil();
                        }
                    }
                }
                return theInstance;
            }

            public void SubmitTask(Runnable runnable) {
                theExecutor.submit(runnable);
            }
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            MainClass main = new MainClass();
            main.MainMethod();
        }
}
```

You might want to clean and rebuild your project. Otherwise it's working..

Comment: Cleaned and rebuilt. But still the same problem!

Comment: @DeepikaMasilamani Whatever you _simplified_ in your code - this one is working. No idea how your actual code looks like..

Comment: I have updated my post. The problem occurs for non-primitive data types. Since java uses 'Call by reference' for non-primitive data types, the value was over written. Sorry for not mentioning the original data type in the post.